# How to check if a generated number already exists

Tags: javascript, loops, scope

This code below creates a random costumer number and prints it out with a simple console log, but one feature is missing: It should check if the same costumer number/ID has already been generated before. If so, it should walk through the process again, so a new random number is generated which then is unique. How can I do that with this code? As a programming newbie I unfortunately have NO clue how I could do that. Maybe a while loop and storing the generated number in a variable? Would be totally awesome if you can provide the code, combined with mine or build in the duplicate-checking feature.

```
    function generateCostumerNum() {

      // generating a random 8-digit number with numbers from 1 to 9
      var zeroToNine = "";
      for (counter = 0; counter <= 7; counter++) {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
        zeroToNine += randomNumber;
      }

      // calculating the cross-sum of the generated number above
      var numberforCrossSum = zeroToNine,
        crossSum = 0;

      while (numberforCrossSum) {
          crossSum += numberforCrossSum % 10;
          numberforCrossSum = Math.floor(numberforCrossSum / 10);
      }

      // building together the final costumer ID string.
      var finalCostumerNum = "ID" + zeroToNine + crossSum;

      console.log(finalCostumerNum);
    };

    generateCostumerNum();
```

Comment: How do you want to persist the data? In a database? On the client?

Comment: For in-memory: Try an object-as-a-set (traditional) or a Set. Otherwise, will need some form or persistence or a method to “generate with ‘guaranteed’ uniqueness”.

Comment: @daddygames On the client with pure JavaScript

Comment: Look up the code to generate an UUID instead. If you're going to create the id numbers randomly, there isn't much you can do expect for checking all the previous id's again, since well, random. But if these aren't stored anywhere, and only valid for that one session, just use an integer and start with customer id 1 every time. Hence the `How do you want to persist the data` question. The word `customer` makes me think that there's money involved. If that is true, I should say that his is probably a bad idea to do client side.

Comment: Do you understand the concept of `scope` for JavaScript variables? Do you know how to use `localStorage`? Do you understand how to work with arrays in JavaScript? Do you want the customer ids to persist even if the browser is closed or the page is refreshed?

Comment: @daddygames Thank you, unfortunately I'm not comfortable yet working with scope, but I know what it is. But don't know how to use the localStorage yet. I also know what basic array methods exist but didn't work with arrays yet. No I just what it only for the one site, as a simple example. It's not planned that the page is refreshed/browser closed.

Comment: @Shilly Thanks. No it's no problem, the customer ID is just an example exercise with no real data. Unfortunately I don't understand what you meant in the comment because I am totally new to programming concepts but I try to google now

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you. I don't know the JavaScript sets yet but I look to find out. So you think there would be no other way? It should just check if the generated number with Math.random() already was created before. If so, repeat the process and very likely the next one will be unique. If its already unique, great, all fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple `while` loop that runs as long as the generated number has already been generated:

```
var already_generated_nums = []; // an array of the numbers already generated
//...
var new_num = generateCostumerNum();

while (already_generated_nums.includes(new_num)) {
    new_num = generateCostumerNum();
}

already_generated_nums.push(new_num);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to put it below the code I already have but it gives me an error: `error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'already_generated_nums.includes')` Do you know what I did wrong, how the right way would be? Do I have to rename the functions or set another parameter than "num"?

Comment: Thanks. Now it says `error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: num`. What is "num", what should it be/is it's role in this case?

Comment: @MrFrontend Just a typo, use `.includes(new_num)`.

Comment: Ahh thank you I think now it works. I google again about the .includes()-method and .push()-method and how they work, but I think that code does it. Thanks!!